# Como conectar a base de dados online do SQL Server pelo JDBC no Netbeans

Tags: java, jdbc

Tenho uma dúvida sobre como gerar a URL de conexão do JDBC em Java no IDE Netbeans,para me conectar com uma base de dados online do SQL Server.

Segue abaixo o meu código, o qual não gerou uma conexão como o banco de dados:

```
  package teste.br.com.DAO;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

 public class ConexaoSQLServer {

    Connection con = null;
    String driverDB = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";

    String rota = "jdbc:sqlserver//sqlserver01.BASE_DADOS.com.br;databaseName=NOME;user=USER;"
            + "password=PASS;";

    public boolean ConectarBD(){
        try{
            Class.forName(driverDB);
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(rota);
            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            ex.getMessage();
            return false;

        }
    }
}
```

Ao realizar o debug no netbeans, verifiquei que o problema é a conexão com a base de dados online.

Comment: Seja bem vindo Igor! Poderia editar sua pergunta e adicionar o erro que é gerado? Ajuda a comunidade a ter ajudar! Muito Obrigado!

Comment: Está faltando a porta, após o host: sqlserver01.BASE_DADOS.com.br:1433

Comment: Dá uma olhada no [connectionstrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/)

Comment: Na verdade não ocorreu nenhum erro ao executar, mesmo colocando o try catch com as exceptions referentes, apenas ao debuggar percebo que minha conexão é nula, vou verificar se a base de dados on-line possui alguma propriedade que não especifiquei na url. Muito obrigado pela ajuda!